# LinearLayout inside a View (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-view

I want to put a LinearLayout inside a View (which represents a rectangle), to put more elements inside this Layout. Unfortunately, this doesn't work somehow, it just doesn't recognize the LinearLayout nor other elements when I put them inside the View.

I use Xamarin.Android (only Android, not iOS) in Visual Studio Community 2019.

Here is the XML Code. The @drawable/rounded is just an .xml file which makes the view a rectangle with round corners.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff74a8a7"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--Header-->

    <TextView
        android:text="MyTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:textColor="#ff2f5858"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!--View-->
    <View
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:backgroundTint="#ff38817a" >

        <!--Here should the next LinearLayout go, e.g.: (does not work!-->
        <LinearLayout>
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--Elements inside this LinearLayout, e.g. a text and a button-->

        </LinearLayout>

    </View>

</LinearLayout>
```

Help would be appreciated on how to solve this problem!

Comment: Can you please provide the layout you are creating, so we can help you figure out what is up?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I added the XML code in the main post, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This part of your layout won't work:

```xml
<View
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:backgroundTint="#ff38817a" >

    <!--Here should the next LinearLayout go, e.g.: (does not work!-->
    <LinearLayout>
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Elements inside this LinearLayout, e.g. a text and a button-->

    </LinearLayout>

</View>
```

A `View` is not a `ViewGroup` and can per design not have any children. You could use `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `ConstraintLayout` or any other layout to host multiple children.

You could just remove the outer view and you should be able to see your `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Hello, firstly I'd like to thank you for the replay. The thing is, I want the View to be there, or any other thing that can display a rectangle with round corners. And inside this rectangle, the LinearLayout should go with its children.

Comment: You can just change `View` to `FrameLayout` to get that desired effect. However, for rounded corners, you don't even need another nested level. You can just apply a `OutlineProvider` and allow the view to clip.